# Nightmare.js script on quora not working properly

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I have written this script to log into quora.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');   
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
  .goto('https://www.quora.com/')
  .type('input[name="email"]','xyz@gmail.com')
  .type('input[type="password"]','pass123')
  .click('input[type="submit"]')
  .wait(5000)
  .click('.disable_click_on_edit_mode')
  .wait(5000)
  .evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelectorAll('.question_link').href;
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error message:', error);
  });
```

It should easily login to quora by entering my email in the email field and my password in my password field and then clicking the login button.

But when i run this script, it enters the email as well as the password, both inside the email field and then results into an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried and found another solution that is working. As only there are two input box in that login page, you can use this:

```
nightmare
  .goto('https://www.quora.com/')
  .type('input[tabindex="1"]','xyz@gmail.com')
  .type('input[tabindex="2"]','pass123')
  .click('input[type="submit"]')
  .wait(5000)
  .click('.disable_click_on_edit_mode')
  .wait(5000)
  .evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelectorAll('.question_link').href;
  })
```